# How to start an activity from a non-ui thread (from a surface view drawing thread)

Tags: java, android, android-activity, thread-safety

I'm developing an android game that uses a surface view for representing the ui graphics. I need to implement a method to start another activity if the user touches a specific area.
for this i'm passing the main (foreground) activity's current instance to the surface view

I can handle the touch easily but cannot start the activity from received instance.

**> if i call startActivity method from the received instance of the

> current activity Exceptions occurs stating that its a call from non
>   ui-thread**

i'm using a class extended to surface view and passed to a thread which draws on its canvas

Comment: THANKS FELLAS I FIGURED IT OUT

i called runOnUI from the class instance and it works perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the SurfaceView within an activity?
If so, use

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    //startActivity
  }
});
```

If you are not within an activity you really shouldn't be starting other activities..

Also SurfaceView has a post and postDelayed methods which can be use to post Runnables on the UI thread.

```
  post(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         //startActivity
       }

   });
```

Comment: well in my app an object of surface view is instantiated in the activity and then the object is passed to setContentView() method of the activity

Comment: I would argue then if it is not directly in an activity that it shouldn't be starting other activities.. It should delegate that to the activity that uses it. I would implement some interface which responds to some event (callback function) from the surfaceview. I would have to see more of your code to help you with that though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this...

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {


           // start your activity here


                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
// from MySurfaceView/Activity
Context context = getContext(); 

//EffectingActivity is another activity
Intent intent = new Intent(context, EffectingActivity.class); 
context.startActivity(intent);
```